# Можно ли в блоке оператора with использовать свойства или методы других объектов?

Tags: delphi

Использую оператор with:

```
With myObject do
begin
  ...
end;
```

В блоке begin ... end есть свойства или методы не только myObject, но и других объектов. Можно ли так делать?

Comment: Если вы явно укажите эти объекты, то, конечно, можно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да можно.
Но если имена свойств или методов совпадают то обращение будет выполняться к myObject.
Если нужно будет обратиться к другому объекту - нужно будет указать его имя пред методом.

Например,

```
with myObject1 do
  with myObject2 do begin
    name1 := name;
    name2 := myObject1.name;
  end;
```

*name1* будет присвоено значение свойства *name* объекта ***myObject2***,
*name2* будет присвоено значение свойства *name* объекта ***myObject1***.

Comment: Спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ!